# Wildcard routing with laravel not following recognizing prefix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

In my application i have a laravel backend with two spas consuming api from it. Now i want to manage my routes by using wildcard routes where i give both routes prefixes before the wildcard route takes effect. Here is an example

```
Route::prefix('creditors')->group(function () {
    Route::any('/{all}', function () {
        return view('creditor');
    })->where(['all' => '.*']);
});
```

Now the issue us if i visit something like /creditors/login the spa returns a 404 not found. I want my spa to start handling routing after "creditors/". How do i go about this?

Comment: Is it still the same if you remove the `prefix` and then just `Route::any('creditors/{all}')` ?

Comment: Yes. I removed the prefix and did that and my spa is returning the 404 error

Comment: How are you using an SPA and returning a view?

Comment: @zjbarg the index.html data goes into the returned view and the assets go into the public folder

Answer (score 0):

- First remove this code :

```
->where(['all' => '.*']);
```

- Second use these commands :

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan route:cache
```

And finally try again.

Comment: Tried all of this. Didn't work for me